# Popover resizing erraticly

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uipopovercontroller, autorotate

I have a UITabBarController inside a UIPopoverController, which I am displaying solely from one UIBarButtonItem. When shown I want the popover to take up the maximum vertical height allowed. It works fine if I tap to display it, then dismiss, and then rotate. However if I have the popover displayed in landscape, and then rotate to portrait, it no longer will fill the entire vertical distance. I have the tab bar controller's content size property set to 320 by 1000, and I have even tried resetting this every time the device rotates. Worse yet, when the user activates the search bar the popover shrinks up extremely small, and stays that way until the app is restarted.

http://cl.ly/3JdC to http://cl.ly/3JdC

Also http://cl.ly/3JVF

How can I stop this, and have the popover always fill up the max vertical size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having the same problem and found out that it only happens when I present the `UIPopoverController` using the method:

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

but it works fine when I use:

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Unfortunately `UIBarButtonItem` does not have a frame Rect you can use with this last method so my fix was to use the `UIToolbar`'s frame and modify `frame.origin.x` and `frame.size.width` accordingly to make the popover appear on the right place next to the UIBarButtonItem.

Hopefully Apple will fix this in next releases of iOS.

Regards

Comment: I put `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(0, 0); self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);` into the `-viewDidAppear:` method and that also worked. Although it feels like a hack.